# RTL8192SU + RTL8191E Linux issue installing driver

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, mandriva

I've read tons of fourms of people getting the onboard RTL8191E working and the RTL8192SU working dif is U = USB they are both N and I have both Toshiba L500D-00T pre-installed Win Vistax64-HP and i have obtained the free Win7x64-HP upgrade the onboard WiFicard sucks and can't hold a stable connection for more then 20 minutes in windows but the USB is amazing.

Now problem is I tried both Ubuntu and Mandriva with no resolve the issue is the onboard drive detects and actually SHOWS that it's there but no wireless networks detect so it's saying no SSID's are broadcasting which I know is a lie since I'm running a 2wire bell dsl modem with built in wifi and a Linksys wrt54g w/ DD-WRT firmware and both are broadcasting fine.

Why don't i use the USB?

> new>> in Mandriva Linux Control Center 2010.0 it shows up in Other/Unknown as RTL8191S WLAN Adapter  and on the right pane this shows up

```
Identification
Vendor: ‎Manufacturer Realtek 

Description: ‎RTL8191S WLAN Adapter 

Media class: ‎

Connection
Bus: ‎USB

Bus PCI #: ‎1

PCI device #: ‎5

Vendor ID: ‎0x0bda

Device ID: ‎0x8172

Sub vendor ID: ‎0x0000

Sub device ID: ‎0x0000

Misc
Module: ‎rtl819xU
```

In the hardware device manager in mandriva it shows up as unknown but shows that it's realtek and that it's a 8192 chipset. but no option to for a driver install and when i do  a `make` in terminal i get this error and no clue what it means

```
[root@John-PC rtl8192se_linux_2.6.0010.1020.2009_64bit]# make
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.31.12-desktop-3mnb/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@John-PC rtl8192se_linux_2.6.0010.1020.2009_64bit]#
```

any help appreciated.

and just encase I'm running currently Mandriva Spring 2010 Free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the solution Kubuntu/Ubuntu x86 9.10 You MUST unfortunately use the win2k drivers

in Kubuntu/Ubuntu 9.10x64 Driver's are disabled w/ fn+keys not fully functionally no way to re-enable

Kubuntu/Ubuntu 10.04 x86/x64 Same issue as 9.10 x64

Mandriva - Gave up after got working on Kubuntu/Ubuntu

Also to my Surprise the on-board was ACTUALLY RTL8191E not rtl8192se

Updating op